# Unable to drop a column from a Pandas DataFrame Object

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a Pandas DataFrame with some data as shown in the below screenshot. While working with it accidentally i created a new column **`(0, 0)`** with the below statement.

```py
P[0,0] = 'Sun'

# Instead of
P.iloc[0,0] = 'Sun'
```

And from then i'm trying to drop the column but i could not succeed.

[image]

How to drop this column with name **`(0, 0)`**.

Comment: Use `df = df.drop((0,0), 1)`

Comment: Thank you @SandeepKadapa. Got it 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `drop`:

```
P.drop(columns=[(0,0)], inplace=True)
```